# How do I get the breakdown of a reputation score in the Reputation table of StackOverflow schema

Tags: stackexchange-api

How do I get the breakdown of a reputation score in the Reputation table of StackOverflow schema. For example, for user with UserId 1, his total score in the Post table is 6,036 but his reputation is over 30,000. How do I get the breakdown of the over 30,000 reputation score in the Reputation table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. You will need to calculate this manually by finding the amount of upvotes, accepted answers and down votes he/she received. However you should also keep in mind that he can gain reputation by editing posts.

You can find this by querying the **VoteTypes** table joined by the posts of that user.

Comment: I thought so too. I just hoped there was an easier way to do it. Thanks

Comment: hi @DJanssens, can you please explain how you do this? I'm a noob here.